# How to make nautilus forget saved password?

Tags: networking, nautilus, samba

I am browsing Shared folders on a Windows network through Samba.

When I first opened a system on the network I was asked for a login username, password and I checked the `save-password` setting. Now the shared folder opens directly without asking for authentication.

I want to browse the folder using a different user which has more access rights. How should I do that?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Hi what ever the passwords you save in Ubuntu will store in seahorse application. type as seahorse in your unity dash and open that application. That will have your password and you can remove from there.

I am currently away from my Ubuntu PC thats why I am  posting available image that could help you a bit.

[image]