# Make nautilus forget shared folder passwords in ubuntu 16

Tags: nautilus, samba

I usually select "remember password until you log out" but I need to troubleshoot the samba server by logging in as a different user (trying to make it so users can delete old backups put up by other users).

Same question for an earlier version of Ubuntu at [How to make nautilus forget saved password?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/236436/how-to-make-nautilus-forget-saved-password) 
but the passwords for shared folders (on samba servers) no longer appear to be saved in "seahorse"/"passwords and keys" (I deleted all passwords and it still automatically logs into the remote folders).

I also tried looking through the hidden files in  .config/nautilus but didn't see anything that looked like a user login listed.