# How to change username in Connect to server?

Tags: nautilus

Once I entered a wrong username and gave "Remember Forever", I can't change the username later. There are answers for change password but I want to change username

Answer (score -2, accepted):

You can use "Connect to Server" option in Nautilus default file browser and login using
ssh://USERNAME@IPAddress/home/

Comment: Hi, is your answer related to the question? Or just information? I do not see the relation.

Answer (score 1):

Even though it is an old post, I just had the same problem so I will write my solution. 
I deleted the related password keyring from "Passwords and Keys" on Ubuntu 18.04. Then I restarted the computer and this time it asked the password again, and putting the right username, domain and password, I could connect to the server.

Answer (score 1):

Just as in [this answer](https://askubuntu.com/questions/236436/how-to-make-nautilus-forget-saved-password#answer-236437).

For any Linux using Gnome Keyring you can use the manager [Seahorse](https://wiki.gnome.org/Apps/Seahorse)
In Ubuntu is already installed and can be found in the applications menu under *Passwords and Keys* (as @syn mentions), but in Xubuntu (for example), it must be installed.

If you open it you have a nice GUI and on the left frame under `Passwords` you find all your stored `Logins`. There you can change the password, but, sadly, you cannot change the user: the only option is following

1. **delete the entry**
2. reconnect to the server with the new user (I had **not** to restart the computer)

Comment: In Ubuntu20, passwrods and keys. Delete the corresponding ssh address.